# Combine objects of same key (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

```
for(i=0; i < results.length; i++){
    var newObj = {};
    newObj.name = results[i].name;
    newObj.impact = [results[i].impact, results[i]['count']];
    filt.push(newObj);
}
```

I looped over the results and generated an array of objects, however I want to combine objects that have the same key ("name").  Potentially the impact values may not contain the same key as there could miss one for example user1 is missing the "3" level but user2 has it.  How can I combine the array of objects to collapse them?

```
{ name: 'User1', impact: [ '1', 1 ] }
{ name: 'User1', impact: [ '2', 1 ] }
{ name: 'User1', impact: [ '4', 2 ] }
{ name: 'User1 ', impact: [ '0', 1 ] }
{ name: 'User2 ', impact: [ '1', 1 ] }
{ name: 'User2 ', impact: [ '2', 1 ] }
{ name: 'User2 ', impact: [ '3', 1 ] }
{ name: 'User2 ', impact: [ '4', 1 ] }
```

Would want it to be:

```
  { name: 'User1', impact: ['0', 1, '1', 1, '2', 1, '3', 0, '4', 2] }
  { name: 'User2', impact: ['0', 1, '1', 1, '2', 1, '3', 1, '4', 1] }
```

Comment: You seem to be using arrays as some kind of hybrid object hashes, with the even indexes functioning as keys and the odd as values. If so, that's a pretty clumsy way of doing what I think you want to do.

Comment: You can use this function: `f=a=>(o={},a.map(x=>o[n=x.name.trim()]=(o[n]||[]).concat(x.impact)),o)` and you can use it like `var result = f(yourArray)`... Hope it helps ;)